# Extend an array from custom index

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, extend

**My try:**

```
squares = [2**2, 3**2, 4**2, 5**2, 6**2, 7**2, 8**2, 9**2]

print(squares)

squares[:1].extend([1])

print(squares)
```

**Output**

> [4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
>
> [4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

so can it be:

> [4, 1, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

this is a simplified example of what I want to do (*in the real world there will be such a larger array to extend and so*).

If you have any suggestions please support.

Comment: are u looking for `squares.insert(1, 1)`?

Comment: what if i want to insert array.

Comment: If you use `squares[:1].extend([1])`, you need to remove `[:1]` to see any difference

Comment: @PCM no doesn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To insert an array, you can use the list slicing

```py
squares = [2**2, 3**2, 4**2, 5**2, 6**2, 7**2, 8**2, 9**2]
squares[1:1] = [1]

print(squares) #[4, 1, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Comment: It would be better if you could also provide an example with OP's code

Answer (score 2):

### Single item:

You could try `list.insert`:

```
>>> squares = [2**2, 3**2, 4**2, 5**2, 6**2, 7**2, 8**2, 9**2]
>>> squares.insert(1, 1)
>>> squares
[4, 1, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
>>>
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> Insert an item at a given position. The first argument is the index of the element before which to insert, so `a.insert(0, x)` inserts at the front of the list, and `a.insert(len(a), x)` is equivalent to `a.append(x)`.

### Multiple items:

Try this:

```
squares[1:1] = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: squares.insert(1,[1])
[4, [1], 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]. i want to insert as array

Comment: @AhmedEl-Ghorory Don't add the brackets, just do `squares.insert(1, 1)`.

Comment: @U12-Forward, he wants to add arrays, of course, it is gonna be in brackets. He used `.extend` so that he could add more elements but it was not a single number as in the example.

Comment: what if i want to insert a list?

Comment: "Try this code: `squares[1:] = squares[:1].extend([1, 2, 3])`" Did you try this code?

Comment: @blhsing Oh was in a rush, forgot to remove that code, edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

Why does it not work as expected?
Look at this:

```py
squares = [2**2, 3**2, 4**2, 5**2, 6**2, 7**2, 8**2, 9**2]

print(squares)

sub = squares[:1]
sub.extend([1])  # This line does not change `squares`
print(sub)
# [1, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]

print(squares)
# [4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

How to fix:

```py
squares = [2**2, 3**2, 4**2, 5**2, 6**2, 7**2, 8**2, 9**2]

print(squares)

def insert_elements(origin_list: list, target_list: list, index: int) -> list:
    return origin_list[:index] + target_list + origin_list[index:]

squares = insert_elements(squares, [1], 1)
print(squares)
# [4, 1, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Comment: @AhmedEl-Ghorory Yes, squares[1:1]=xxx looks more magic